# Pandas: how do I restart expanding function with each new day in my time-series?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using expanding method in my dataset. I know how to use it, for example:

```
data["someColumn"].expanding().mean()
```

The challenge is that my dataset contains time series, and I need to "restart" expanding method when a new day starts. I.e. when new day starts expanding should treat first row of a new day as the only available data, then second row is second data etc till the day ends.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put there sample small dataframe and expected output.

Comment: You can group the data by day and then apply the expanding method to each group separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your time series is being used as your dataframe's index, you can create a new column with the indexes dates and then perform a `df.groupby("date").expanding().mean()`:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"B": [1, 2, 4, 0, 4]},
    index=pd.to_datetime(
        ["2023-12-11 21:00:00", "2023-12-11 22:00:00", "2023-12-11 23:00:00",
         "2023-12-12 00:00:00", "2023-12-12 01:00:00"]
    )
)

# Uncomment this line if you want the index to be sorted.
# df = df.sort_index()

df["day"] = df.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

df.groupby("day").expanding().mean()
# Returns:
#
#                                        B
# day                                     
# 2023-12-11 2023-12-11 21:00:00  1.000000
#            2023-12-11 22:00:00  1.500000
#            2023-12-11 23:00:00  2.333333
# 2023-12-12 2023-12-12 00:00:00  0.000000
#            2023-12-12 01:00:00  2.000000
```

Comment: This assumes the data is sorted in time order for each day (or that OP wants order as in the data whether or not that is in time order).

Comment: @user19077881 Edited the answer and added the option to sort the index